# How does the psionic power Immovability actually work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics, concentration

The psionic power [Immovability](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/immovability.htm) has a duration of "Concentration".

Does it mean that I need to roll more than 10 on the Concentration check each round to keep manifesting it if I'm not under attack, and roll more than (10 + damage dealt) to keep it under pressure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *[Duration](http://dndsrd.net/psionicDescriptions.html#duration): Concentration* entry of the 4th-level psychic warrior power [***immovability***](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersGtoP.html#immovability) [psychometabolism] (*Expanded Psionics Handbook* 112) means that

> The power lasts as long as you concentrate on it. Concentrating to maintain a power is a standard action that does not provoke attacks of opportunity. Anything that could break your concentration when manifesting a power can also break your concentration while you’re maintaining one, causing the power to end. You can’t manifest a power while concentrating on another one. (61)

Thus the manifester on each of the manifester's turns must take a standard action to concentrate on the power to maintain it, but the power does *not* normally require the manifester make a [Concentration](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#table-concentration) skill check to maintain it.

However, while the power's duration continues, if the manifester is subject to [effects that can disrupt concentration](http://dndsrd.net/psionic.html#concentration), the manifester makes Concentration skill checks normally, with success meaning that the power's duration continues and failure meaning that the power's duration ends.

In practice, this means that the psychic warrior can take a standard action to manifest the *immovability* power then, so long as the manifester on each of the manifester's turns continues to take a standard action to concentrate, the power's duration continues. Attacks that deal damage to the manifester and other effects, though, may require the manifester to make Concentration skill check to maintain the power's duration, but if nothing interferes and the manifester's okay with spending a standard action each turn to maintain the power's duration, the power's duration can continue as long as the manifester wants.

Comment: A link to the question I’m pretty sure we’ve got about when you’re allowed to end concentration might be useful here, since that’s a contentious subject.

Comment: @KRyan You mean [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106511/8610)? That doesn't seem particularly controversial, but the link in this comment does put in the Linked section of the sidebar.